# Use conditional criteria to change Row_Number like operation

Tags: sql-server, variables, data-partitioning

Using SQL server 2012.  I am using variables to identify the number of times "various criteria" are met within my overall dataset.  And I want to take half of these instances and do one thing "first_half_thing" and with the other half do a "second_half_thing".  It works okay when I only include those instances where criteria are met.  But I want to perform this operation on my whole data set with 3 or 4 different versions of the "various criteria".

My first try was to try and change the value of @CriteriaMetCount when the "various criteria" are met and use that count to do either the "first_half_thing" or the "second_half_thing" but that didn't work.  Is there a way to `Partition by` and then use different sets of "various criteria"

```
declare @TargetNumber BIGINT
declare @TargetHalf BIGINT
declare @CriteriaMetCount BIGINT

set @CriteriaMetCount=1
Set @TargetNumber=(

select count(distinct(AI2.AccountID)) from Table_AccountInfo AI2
where
AI2.OrgID in (
    select distinct(Org2.OrgID) from Table_Organization Org2
        where Org2.OrganizationName like ('%Name%'))
and (various criteria here)
)

Set @TargetHalf= (select iif(
(@TargetNumber%2)>0,((@TargetNumber+1)/2),(@TargetNumber/2)))

select  AI.AccountID, @targethalf, @targetnumber,ROW_Number() over(order by AI.AccountID) AS ROW_COUNT,
case when ((ROW_Number() over(order by AI.AccountID))<=@targethalf) then  'first_half_thing' else 'second_half_thing' end, 
iif(((ROW_Number() over(order by AI.AccountID))%2=0),(@CriteriaMetCount+1),@CriteriaMetCount)


from Table_AccountInfo LI
where AI.AccountID >= @TargetNumber
and AI.OrgID in (
        select distinct(Org.OrgID) from Table_Organization Org
        where Org.OrganizationName like ('%Name%')) 


and (various criteria here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did this: added a temp table which did the first operation (evaluated entire data set for "various criteria") and then did an easy `case when` to check the current AccountID vs the ones stored in the temp table.

My first experience using a temp table in such fashion and it worked, so there you go.